# Maven creates a jar file but does not add any dependencies to it

Tags: java, maven

The build process ends successfully and I receive a jar file, but when I try to run it I get ClassNotFoundException: : com.javarush.games.racer.RacerGame

My pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>jru.module3</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>localrep</id>
            <name>local repository</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>18.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.javarush</groupId>
            <artifactId>desktop-game-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>D:/JDE/IDE/projects/project-maven-master/lib/desktop-game-engine.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>
                    D:\JDE\IDE\projects\project-maven-master\lib\
                </directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.jar</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
            <directory>
                D:\JDE\IDE\projects\project-maven-master\src\main\java\com\javarush\games\racer\
            </directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.class</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>18</source>
                    <target>18</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                    <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestFile>D:\JDE\IDE\projects\project-maven-master\resources\MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Rsrc-Main-Class>com.javarush.games.racer.RacerGame</Rsrc-Main-Class>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    </configuration>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <groupId>com.javarush</groupId>
                    <artifactId>desktop-game-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <packaging>jar</packaging>
                    <file>${basedir}/lib/desktop-game-engine.jar</file>
                    <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Run java-fx app over Maven -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.javarush.games.racer.RacerGame</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${basedir}/lib/
                    </outputDirectory>
                    <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to add  block to all pom,tried att resources to plugins, tried to change building steps in plugins change plugin settings but to no avail.

Comment: As I understand, maven-assembly-plug is replacement for maven-jar-plugin, but I want to use the last one or am I wrong?

Comment: I tried to use the solution from the provided link, but it remains the same